# Using an integer reference in a let expression

Tags: ocaml

I am attempting a code sample in Lesson 5, Step 6 of the
[Try Ocaml tutorial](https://try.ocamlpro.com/)

We were supposed to fix this code sample:

```
let one =
  let accum = ref -54 in
  for i = 1 to ten do accum := !accum + i done ;
  !accum
```

and here is my attempt:

```
let one =
  let accum = ref -54 in (
      for i = 1 to 10 do
        accum := accum + i
      done
    ;
      !accum
    )
```

but unfortunately I am receiving the error message:

> line 2, characters 14-17: Error: This expression has type 'a -> 'a ref
>          but an expression was expected of type int

Answer (score 2):

You're missing parentheses around `-54`.

```
let one =
  let accum = ref (-54) in
  for i=1 to 10 do
    accum := !accum + i
  done;
  !accum
;;
```

`ref` is a function that has type `'a -> 'a ref`, and the minus operator `(-)` has type `int -> int -> int`. Here, `54` is an `int` but `ref` is not, hence the type error message.

Comment: You can also use `~-` which is the prefix integer negation operator, avoiding the need to wrap extra parens.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

One weirdness of the lexer of ocaml is that `-54` corresponds to two tokens.

Hence, your code corresponds to 

`let accum = ref (-) 54 in`

which yields the mentioned type error. The solution is to add parenthesis and write `(-54)`.